# Apply function along time dimension of XArray

Tags: dask, python-xarray

I have an image stack stored in an XArray DataArray with dimensions time, x, y on which I'd like to apply a custom function along the time axis of each pixel such that the output is a single image of dimensions x,y.

I have tried: apply_ufunc but the function fails stating that I need to first load the data into RAM (i.e. cannot use a Dask Array). Ideally, I'd like to keep the DataArray as Dask Arrays internally as it isn't possible to load the entire stack into RAM. The exact error message is:

> ValueError: apply_ufunc encountered a dask array on an argument, but handling for dask arrays has not been enabled. Either set the `dask` argument or load your data into memory first with `.load()` or `.compute()`

My code currently looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd 

def special_mean(x, drop_min=False):
    s = np.sum(x)
    n = len(x)
    if drop_min:
    s = s - x.min()
    n -= 1
    return s/n

times = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-10', name='time')

data = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(10, 8, 8), dims=["time", "y", "x"], coords={'time': times})
data = data.chunk({'time':10, 'x':1, 'y':1})

res = xr.apply_ufunc(special_mean, data, input_core_dims=[["time"]], kwargs={'drop_min': True})
```

If I do load the data into RAM using .compute then I still end up with an error which states:

> ValueError: applied function returned data with unexpected number of dimensions: 0 vs 2, for dimensions ('y', 'x')

I'm not sure entirely what I am missing/doing wrong.

Comment: `apply_ufunc` is likely still the way to go. Can you provide an example of what you've tried?  A MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be a help in getting your question answered.

Comment: I've updated the question to include a MCVE and the exact errors

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
def special_mean(x, drop_min=False):
    s = np.sum(x)
    n = len(x)
    if drop_min:
        s = s - x.min()
    n -= 1
    return s/n

times = pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2019-01-10', name='time')

data = xr.DataArray(np.random.rand(10, 8, 8), dims=["time", "y", "x"], coords={'time': times})
data = data.chunk({'time':10, 'x':1, 'y':1})

res = xr.apply_ufunc(special_mean, data, input_core_dims=[["time"]], kwargs={'drop_min': True}, dask = 'allowed', vectorize = True)
```

The code above using the `vectorize` argument should work.

Comment: please give some explaination of you modification

Comment: `ValueError: applied function returned data with unexpected number of dimensions. Received 0 dimension(s) but expected 2 dimensions with names: ('y', 'x')`

Answer (score 0):

My aim was also to implement apply_ufunc from Xarray such that it can compute the special mean across x and y.

I enjoyed Ales example; of course by omitting the line related to the chunk. Otherwise:

```
ValueError: applied function returned data with unexpected number of dimensions. Received 0 dimension(s) but expected 2 dimensions with names: ('y', 'x')
```

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, I realized that, in a situation, to have the output of apply_ufunc 3D instead of 2D, we need to add "out_core_dims=[["time"]]" to the apply_ufunc.